# Struggling with archiving of log files from parent and children directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have used a few entries here to guide me through my following bash script:

```
LOG_FILES=$(find ~/testing.domain.net -name "domain_*log" -printf ' %P ')
NEW_LOG_FILES=$(echo $LOG_FILES | sed -e 's/\r//g')
echo ${NEW_LOG_FILES}
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
echo ${NOW}
tar czf ${NOW}.tar.gz ${NEW_LOG_FILES}
RC=$? # Check whether an error occured
if [[ "$RC" == "0" ]]; then
    mv ${NOW}.tar.gz archivedlogs/.
    rm ${LOG_FILES}
fi
```

The objective of the script is to find any log files in the current and sub directories and tar zipped them all before moving tar file to an `archivedlogs` subdirectory and then deleting log files.

When I execute the script I'm getting:

```
domain_info_log subdir1/domain_error_log subdir2/domain_error_log domain_error_log
12-27-2020
tar: \r\r: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
./archiveTestLogsDaily.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I can't seem to get rid of the carriage returns.

I have also tried replacing:

```
NEW_LOG_FILES=$(echo $LOG_FILES | sed -e 's/\r//g')
```

with:

```
NEW_LOG_FILES=${LOG_FILES//$'\r'/}
```

But same outcome.

Any ideas? My bash script knowledge is not the best but I'm guessing the find part comes back with carriage returns?

Also before anyone else suggests it, I don't have access to logrotate as this is a shared server.

```
$ uname -a
Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.26.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 11 10:29:54 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which OS, distribution and version do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.26.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 11 10:29:54 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be more safe to use a directory before making the tar archive in order to avoid a "tarbomb".

I mean something like:

```
now="$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")"
archiv_dir="archiv_dir-${now}"
mkdir -p "${archiv_dir}"
find ~/testing.domain.net -type f -a -iname "domain_*log" -exec mv {} "${archiv_dir}" \; 
tar cvzf "${now}.tar.gz" "${archiv_dir}" && mv "${now}.tar.gz" "archivedlogs/" && rm -rf "${archiv_dir}"
```

P.S: make sure to double quote when you're using a variable value in Bash (or even using other POSIX shells), except inside `[[`.

EDIT to answer to that:

> One more thing @Idriss, some of those subdirectories have the same file names, when mv tries to copy them it ignores them because they are already there... is there a way of making sure the parent directory is somehow appended to the name?

With a little bit of `bash` and `awk`, you could try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

now="$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")"
archiv_dir="archiv_dir-${now}"

ROOT=~/testing.domain.net
find "${ROOT}" -type f -a -iname "domain_*log"|while read; do 
  subdir="$(echo $REPLY|awk -F '/' '{print $(NF-1)}')"
  filename="$(basename "${REPLY}")"
  [[ $subdir && $subdir != $(basename $ROOT) ]] && filename="${subdir}_${filename}"
  echo mv "${REPLY}" "${archiv_dir}/${filename}"
done
```

Here is the output:

```
mv /Users/ineumann/testing.domain.net/subdir3/domain_error_log archiv_dir-12-28-2020/subdir3_domain_error_log
mv /Users/ineumann/testing.domain.net/subdir2/domain_error_log archiv_dir-12-28-2020/subdir2_domain_error_log
mv /Users/ineumann/testing.domain.net/subdir1/domain_error_log archiv_dir-12-28-2020/subdir1_domain_error_log
mv /Users/ineumann/testing.domain.net/domain_info_log archiv_dir-12-28-2020/domain_info_log
```

N.B: just remove the `echo` before the `mv` to perform the moves and I let you merge this example with your previous script that create directories, create the tar archive, etc.

Comment: Hey there, I tried this and it does look like a much better approach (thanks for that), upon trying it however I get:

```
ux42jqcv@lhcp3114 [~/testing.domain.net]$ ./archiveTestLogs2.sh
tar: Substituting `.' for empty member name
tar: : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Seems the find also finds the . and the .. and tar is not liking that

Comment: My example had some errors on the variable name (I had `archiv_dir` and `archive_dir`. I've edited my answer so be sure that you have the same variable name everywhere.

Comment: Nvm, I had not renamed the -name value correctly so it was not finding anything hence the error

Comment: ok will try that, after I had fixed my -name, I'm getting:

```
mv: target '/home/ux42jqcv/testing.domain.net/domain_info_log' is not a directory
```

These are files...

Comment: still getting same error... any ideas? Maybe it needs double quotes but how to do it in {} ? i.e. on this part of the  line : -exec mv {} "${archiv_dir}" {} \;

Comment: `{}` must not be repeated twice and it's the pointer on the result you want to move: try something like `-exec mv {} "${archiv_dir}" \;`

Comment: Yes that was it... I was coming back to tell you I also figured it out. thanks again

Comment: One more thing @Idriss,  some of those subdirectories have the same file names, when mv tries to copy them it ignores them because they are already there... is there a way of making sure the parent directory is somehow appended to the name?

Comment: Thanks Idriss for all your help, I managed to put it all together and have learnt some new bash skills from you... you rock!

Comment: @JoseCorreia Thanks, glad I could help!